# django subcategory slug filter

Tags: python, django, categories, slug

Getting my head around Django and followed the tango with Django book, but this last issue gets me after adding subcategories, which are not included in that tutorial.

I have the following:

```
models.py
class Category(models.Model):
"""Category"""
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
slug = models.SlugField()


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

                    #self.slug = slugify(self.name)
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
            super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name


class SubCategory(models.Model):
"""Sub Category"""
category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
slug = models.SlugField()

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
            super(SubCategory, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

and

```
urls.py
(r'^links/$', 'rango.views.links'),
(r'^links/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', 'rango.views.category'),  
(r'^links/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/(?P<subcategory_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', 'rango.views.subcategory'),
```

and

```
views.py
@require_GET
def links(request):
"""Linkdirectory Page"""
category_list = Category.objects.order_by('name')
context_dict = {'categories': category_list}
return render(request, 'links.html', context_dict)

@require_GET
def category(request, category_name_slug):
"""Category Page"""
category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
subcategory_list = SubCategory.objects.filter(category=category)
context_dict = {'subcategories': subcategory_list}
return render(request, 'category.html', context_dict)

@require_GET
def subcategory(request, subcategory_name_slug, category_name_slug):
"""SubCategory Page"""
context_dict = {}
try:
    subcategory = SubCategory.objects.get(slug=subcategory_name_slug)
    context_dict['subcategory_name'] = subcategory.name
    websites = Website.objects.filter(sub_categories=subcategory)
    context_dict['websites'] = websites
    context_dict['subcategory'] = subcategory
except SubCategory.DoesNotExist:
return render(request, 'subcategory.html', context_dict)
```

This all works nicely up to the point I add subcategories with the same name, e.g. the subcategory "other" for multiple categories.

I understand why, when I reach "def subcategory" my slug will return multiple subcategories so I need to limit these to the related category in some way, like a

```
"SELECT 
subcategory = SubCategory.objects.get(slug=subcategory_name_slug)
WHERE 
subcategory = SubCategory.objects.filter(category=subcategory)
CLAUSE"
```

or something ;)

Not sure what's the best route to take on this and how to filter these

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you may have two different `SubCategory` objects with the same name for two different `Category` objects, as you suggested you can add the `Category` as an additional filter.

### Filter by both SubCategory.slug and Category.slug

To achieve this I see you have a view that takes slugs for both `SubCategory` and `Category`, that you defined like this `subcategory(request, subcategory_name_slug, category_name_slug)`. Those are sufficient to filter:

```
subcategory = SubCategory.objects.get(
    slug=subcategory_name_slug,
    category__slug=category_name_slug
)
           ^
           |__ # This "double" underscore category__slug is a way to filter
               # a related object (SubCategory.category)
               # So effectively it's like filtering for SubCategory objects where
               # SubCategory.category.slug is category_name_slug
```

You see above I've used `SubCateogry.objects.get(...)` to get a single object instead of `SubCategory.objects.filter(...) which can return many objects.

### Enforcing *unicity* of SubCategory.name per Category

To do this safely with `get()`, there needs to be a guarantee that for any given Category, there will *no more than one* Subcategory with the same name

You can enforce this condition with [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

```
class SubCategory(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('category', 'name'),          # since slug is based on name,
                                           # we are sure slug will be unique too
        )
```